c#.net GraphServiceClient Sharepoint ListItem working with Choice Field UntypedArray
I am using C#.net GraphServiceClient to manipulate a Sharepoint ListItem. I'm able to access the Field using IDictionary<string, object> AdditionalData.
Assume my field name is EnvironmentTypes, which is a Sharepoint Choice field that allows multiple selections. When I access this field through AdditionalData it's returned as Microsoft.Kiota.Abstractions.Serialization.UntypedArray.
How do I work with this as a List or a string array? I need to update the values in this Field.
The following code:
foreach (var environmentType in AdditionalData["EnvironmentTypes"].GetValue())
    Console.WriteLine(KiotaJsonSerializer.SerializeAsString(environmentType));

Gives me a string delimeted by "; " a semi colon and space.
Surely, there must be a more friendly optimal way to access this value and update it?

See the answer to this question: .NET Graph SDK Updating Sharepoint Online List Item Values which is shown in the screen capture below. It shows the JSON required to set the value of the multi-choice field.
Note: if you're using a more recent version of the Microsoft Graph SDK, you'll need to change the Graph Client call to the following.
Add:
graphClient.Sites[siteId].Lists[listId].Items.PostAsync()
or
Update:
graphClient.Sites[siteId].Lists[listId].Items[itemId].Fields.PatchAsync()
See the Microsoft Graph API reference for more information.


Doesn't work... no such method as Request() on Items.

Updated my answer with additional detail
